# Payment Issues for Restaurant WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm Foodo - [Restaurant WordPress Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/foodo-fast-food-restaurant-wordpress-theme/23460056?irgwc=1&clickid=yn:R59XNtxyORfPwUx0Mo3QWUkE0UpXsDws5TU0&iradid=275988&irpid=1258027&iradtype=ONLINE_TRACKING_LINK&irmptype=mediapartner&mp_value1=&utm_campaign=af_impact_radius_1258027&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=impact_radius&utm_source=Stackover&utm_medium=description&utm_campaign=Free_traffic) from Themelexus. I find in Dashboard but can not find the options for Pay by Card.

Do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is paid Theme on Themeforest, so you can get the support from Themelexus author directly to get good solution.